# Picture to Video augmented reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm new to augmented reality.

What I need to achieve is detecting a picture and inside the same canvas, run the video ( To give the effect that pic get animated)

I saw artoolkit can do it, but as I don't know a lot about those technologies, what is the best ( easiest ) free framework to achieve that.

Availability for iOs should be considered as almost necessary.

Tx !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in any available AR SDK that supports image recognition and tracking (e.g Metaio, Wikitude, Vuforia).
All you need to do is to create a video that is exactly the same size as your target image (the one to be recognized). Then you need to use a morphing tool that creates an animation starting from your target image. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNcgxEOt_rM) of how I did it on a magazine cover, for the sake of demonstrating the MPEG ARAF Browser.
Once you have the video you can place it on the recognized target image as you would place any augmentation content on top of printed material.

Comment: they are all free as long as you don't want to use their recognition servers or some other services that are indeed paid (e.g. cloud database with lots of target images).

Comment: Tx! What should be keywords associated to converting pic to video as you do in your example? I'm lost with all AR vocabulary

Comment: "video morphing software" e.g. Abrosoft FantaMorph, Magic Morph.